# Magento 2 remove lazy load header cart with items

Tags: magento2, cart, javascript

We are currently developing a new Magento 2.3 store, but we find out that items in the cart in the header, are loaded quite late.

When we load a page on frontend, first the entire page loads and then the items in the header cart are loaded. So it first seems that there are no products in the cart and after a few seconds they are displayed.

Is there a way to load the cart with items instant, instead of the lazy load after the page is loaded completly?